# How to autofill a DatePicker when other datepicker is selected in yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm using 2amigos Datepicker and trying to fill o_followup datepicker automatically when I'm selecting o_orderdate datepicker. This is same question as [Second datepicker is not populating onChange of 1st in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815144/second-datepicker-is-not-populating-onchange-of-1st-in-yii2). Please help.
Code of o_orderdate datepicker -

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'o_orderdate')->widget(
                    DatePicker::className(), [
                    // inline too, not bad
                     'inline' => false,
                     // modify template for custom rendering
                    //'template' => '<div class="well well-sm" style="background-color: #fff; width:250px">{input}</div>',
                    'clientOptions' => [
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'todayHighlight' => true,
                        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                    ]
                    ]);?>
```

Code of o_followup datepicker

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'o_followup')->widget(
                    DatePicker::className(), [
                    // inline too, not bad
                     'inline' => false, 
                     // modify template for custom rendering
                    //'template' => '<div class="well well-sm" style="background-color: #fff; width:250px">{input}</div>',
                    'clientOptions' => [
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'todayHighlight' => true,
                        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'

                    ]
                    ]);?>
```

Javascript I've tried -

```
<?php
/* start getting the followupdate */
$script = <<<EOD
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#orders-o_followup").datepicker();
    $("#orders-o_orderdate").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(){
            var fecha = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            $("#orders-o_followup").datepicker("setDate", new Date(fecha.getTime()));
            $("#orders-o_followup").datepicker("setDate", "+365d");
        }
    });
});
EOD;
$this->registerJs($script);
/*end getting the followupdate */
?>
```

Nothing happens at all when I'm selecting the o_orderdate datepicker. Please help.

Partially Working

```
<?php
/* start getting the followupdate */
$script = <<<EOD
$("#orders-o_orderdate").change(function(){ 
    $("#orders-o_followup").datepicker();
    var fecha = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            $("#orders-o_followup").datepicker("setDate", new Date(fecha.getTime()));
            $("#orders-o_followup").datepicker("setDate", "+365d");
});
EOD;
$this->registerJs($script);
/*end getting the followupdate */
?>
```

This code is populating date in o_followup datepicker. But if I change the o_orderdate again it doesn't respond. It remains stuck the initial changed value. and secondly the dateformat is "mm/dd/yyyy". But I want "yyyy-mm-dd". Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#orders-o_followup").change(function(){ 
// do do do ;)
});
```

on change do what do u want dear )

Comment: Hi Izzat, I've changed the code as you said and got result partially. I've added my present situation in the question. Please have a look and let me know what to do.

Comment: The update I wrote in the question is not working at all. o_followup only selecting +365 days from today.